# Does a transaction lock linked tables?

Tags: sql, transactions, locking

I wonder if a transaction which would lock a table will lock all other linked tables too?

Example:

Table 1:

```
userId | ready
--------------
    3  |  1
    1  |  0
   ... | ...
```

Table 2:

```
id | name
----------
0  | John
1  |  0
n  | ...
```

Table 1 has a foreign key to table 2.

Table 2's id is a Pkey.

If I update table 1 in a transaction, will it lock table 2?

If I update table 2 in a transaction, will it lock table 1?

[EDIT]

More info:
Lock escalation: Table
userId is link by a foreign key to id.

I hope this is enough information.

Comment: It depends on how you do your transaction, how the tables/foreign keys are set up, if the database supports row-level locking or only table-level, etc... Without any details of your DB server, table types, and what kind of queries you're running, no way to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>In neither database of the big four (`Oracle`, `SQL Server`, `PostgreSQL`, `MySQL`) an update to one linked table will lock another table</strike>

Yes it may lock the tables, please see the `@a_horse_with_no_name`'s comment.

Moreover, if your reference constraints are defined as `CASCADE` or `SET NULL`, then the update to the master table will trigger an update on the child table, which of course will lock the child table as well.

Comment: That's not entirely true. In Oracle the child table **is** locked during an update (or delete) of the parent table when the FK column is not indexed. For details see this chapter of the manual: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10743/data_int.htm#sthref3094

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: nice point. Please post it as an answer and I'll ask the @op to accept yours instead.

Comment: if the OP is not using Oracle it doesn't matter. And he did not tell us which DBMS is being used.